# How to fix the error "Failed host lookup: 'viacep.com.br'"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http

I'm trying to use an API in flutter, but when I call it I get this error. I've tried everything and haven't succeeded.

```bash
_NativeSocket.lookup.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:520)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)
_NativeSocket.staggeredLookup.<anonymous closure>.lookupAddresses.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:0)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)
```

[image: Debug]

The API I'm using is [Viacep](https://viacep.com.br/). It's working perfectly.

My code is the Flutter base, I just used the floating button to run the simple request:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Título',
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var response = await get(Uri.parse("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/"));
          print(response.body);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've already placed `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and the error has continued.

How can I return the API call?

Comment: What is the parent element of  `<uses-permission/>` in manifest?

Comment: This `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>`

Comment: ok ... I've asked because many people put it under `<application />`